# Should Postgres USER/ROLE management be done with Flyway?

Tags: postgresql, migration, data-versioning

I've recently inherited a company database. The current practice is to put everything schema-related in a Flyway migration and obviously we never change the schema outside of Flyway. This includes `USER` and `ROLE` operations but does it need to?

**Will creating/altering roles outside of Flyway break migration continuity?**

I'm wondering if we are unnecessarily hampering ourselves by forcing every role change to be made through Flyway.

Comment: As to roles being data or schema, it probably depends on how you use them. My personal opinion would be that roles are schema - if I was creating a new empty database with the same schema, I would almost certainly want to move not just tables, indexes, code modules, etc. but also roles.

Comment: I removed the question that may be opinion-based. I appreciate your opinion as well though @RDFozz. It is definitely helpful. I think we will continue to manage our roles through flyway migrations. I'm still curious as to whether not doing so would break Flyway.